# How can I run a C++ program as a Simulink block?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++, udp, simulink

I programmed a UDP socket in C++ in order to receive a string from another program. Now I need to use the data in a Simulink project. I tried the UDP-receiver block in Simulink but I can't separate the data string, so I prefer to try running my UDP socket (in C++) as a block in Simulink. I know that I should use a S-function but I don't know how or if there is another possibility.

Comment: What kind of problem are you having with the output of the Simulink UDP receiver block? That might be easier to resolve than creating your own S-Function, especially if you're not familiar with writing S-Functions.

Comment: After the UDP Receiver block I put an ASCII Decoder block. I send "X:3.14 Y:55" and after the ASCII Decoder I receive (in a Display block) "00301400055". One solution can be a way to distinguish letters, symbols and separate it as variables.

Comment: I've never used the xPC Target and/or Instrument Control toolboxes, so I can't help you with the details, but can't you feed the output of the UDP block into a MATLAB function block and parse the data? If you don't care about code generation from the model, the parsing can be done easily using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature called the `Legacy Code Tool` which should do what you are after. Essentially, it simplifies the process of defining custom Simulink S-function blocks when using existing `C`/`C++`. I seem to remember that there are a few limitations when using `C++` instead of `C` but I don't think they are too significant...